# Is it possible to make a max-pooling on dynamic length sentences without padding in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's assume I have three set of different tensors:

```
x1 = torch.randn(3,16)
x2 = torch.randn(5,16)
x3 = torch.randn(2,16)
```

For each of them, I want to apply a max-pooling and get `1x16` dimensional tensor as output. Is there a way to do that without padding input tensors ? 
I mean, I think I can do what I want by first padding x1 and x3 tensors so that they also become 5x16 tensors. and then I can apply maxpool1d() operator to get what I want.

Comment: do you want `1x16` dimensional output from all 3 tensors? Or, do you want to apply max-pooling on the concatenated tensor get just one output tensor of shape `1x16`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can simply apply `MaxPool1d()` to any size, and they will be (probably) automatically padded. Note that, unfortunately, you need to switch up your dimensions, as it will by default look for pooling along the third dimension.

Here is a short working example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

op = nn.MaxPool1d(5) # kernel size of 5
x1 = torch.zeros([1,16,1])
x2 = torch.zeros([1,16,3])

op(x1) # works

op(x2) # works as well
```

To get your tensor in the correct dimension, you can use `.view()`, in a combination with `.unsqueeze`. Assuming you have a your given `x1` with dimension `(2,16)`, simply do

```
x1.view(16,2).unsqueeze(dim=0)
```

and afterwards perform the reverse transformation by

```
result_x1 = op(x1).view(1,16) # only one value left due to pooling
```